# Populating a combobox with specific items from a text file

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a text file with records of machines stored on it, a single record looks like this:

"1234567890","12/04/2013","Saw","Hilti","17/11/2012",#TRUE#,#FALSE#,#FALSE#,"Made odd noise when operating"

What I would like to achieve is to populate a combo box with only the first item of each record - the serial number - so as to be able to search for the machine in a form based on the selected serial number. I need it to read the file, pick out the serial number from each record, fill the combo box with them, then allow you to select the one that you want.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Since a CBO can store objects, you could store the whole record and only display the first field

Comment: Can we see some code that you've attempted yourself?
Without seeing anything, my intial advice would be to use a IO stream reader. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, how would I achieve this?

Comment: KyleHodgetts - I don't have any code attempting to solve my issue, I've only done basic file handling in the past so I'm not very experienced with much of this. Could you explain the IO stream reader in layman's terms?

Comment: the best starting point is (always) google

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a CSV formatted text file you can store info in a datatable and store each datarow in your cb, and use the DisplayMember property of the combobox to show only the first column. You also need that first line has the names of the columns to achieve this.

Try this supposing the first column is called Serial:

```
 For Each r as DataRow in table.Rows
 combobox1.Items.Add(r)
 Next
 combobox1.DisplayMember("Serial")
```

If not, you can still use your streamreader to obtain each line and split it to obtain first field.
Try:

```
Do
   Dim line As String = reader.readLine()
   If line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
   Dim fields as String() = Split(line, ",")
   combobox1.Items.Add(fields(0))
Loop
```

Hope it helps. You may have to use SubString method to retire the quotes. I post it apart:

replace

```
combobox1.Items.Add(fields(0))
```

by

```
combobox1.Items.Add(fields(0).SubString(1,fields(0).length -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple app and you're happy to use the reader mentioned above, you can also do the following. I've used Replace() instead of Substring().

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "yourFile.txt"))
Dim input = "", fields() As String

While (Not reader.EndOfStream)
    input = reader.ReadLine()
    fields = input.Split(",")
    Dim itemToAdd = fields(0).Replace("""", "")
    ComboBox.Items.Add(itemToAdd)
End While
```

Comment: Very clever. Never thought Replace method could be used that way. +1

Comment: If you want to be _really_ clever you can do `ComboBox.Items.Add(reader.ReadLine().Split(",")(0).Replace("""", ""))`

Comment: Of course. But the way you exposed it is more reader-friendly and understandable.

Comment: That's what I was going for. Everyone has to start somewhere. :)